# JSF2.0 PrimeFaces Navigation Problem

Tags: redirect, dialog, jsf-2, navigation, primefaces

I have a problem with navigation too right now. I have 2 dataTables, one is located within a regular facelets-page, the other one is located in a dialog.
Both have the same code:

```
<p:commandButton
   value="Show car"
   ajax="false"
   action="showCar?faces-redirect=true">
   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{carBean.car}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

I also tried adding process="@this" without success.

The problem is, while the navigation works for the commandButton inside the facelets-page, it doesnt work for the button inside the dialog. It seems that the current page is reloaded after the click.
Replacing it with a  doesn't help either.

Has anybody experienced something like this before? Could this be an issue with the dialog?

Thanks and best regards,
Robert

Comment: Firebug is really useful for finding out what's going on. Look for validationFailed=true in the ajax response. You'll find in that case that your action listener isn't being called. I was trying to do pretty much the same thing as you and just gave up, instead moving the form from the dialog to another page. I might revisit it if/when someone suggests a workable usage pattern for a form inside a p:dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Forget my previous answer, I didn't read your question carefully. What might be happening is a failure in your `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` call. If it is (silently) failing then the error will cause JSF to automatically navigate back to the same page.

Add this to your page somewhere so you can see any helpful error FacesMessages that may be provided by the framework:

```
<p:messages
    id="messagesForDebugging"
    showDetail="true"
    autoUpdate="true" />
```

The `autoUpdate` will cause it flash up messages generated by global Ajax requests.

You may also want to put a logging statement in your `carBean.setCar()` method to make sure that it is successfully setting the value. If it is failing then maybe you need to provide a custom converter for `Car` values?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim, but ajax="true" is the default behavior, which prevents the default JSF-navigation to happen, therfore not working for me. But I really appreciate your response!